# Xquery for nested payload xml

Tags: xquery

Here is my input XML:

This is my modified xml data as input

```
 <Input>
    <BIKey></BIKey>
    <BusinessObjects>
          <BusinessObject>
            <BusinessIdentifiers>
              <BusinessIdentifier>
                <BKey>BuCode</BKey>
                <BValue>CDC</BValue>
              </BusinessIdentifier>
              <BusinessIdentifier>
                <BKey>BuType</BKey>
                <BValue>123</BValue>
              </BusinessIdentifier>
              <BusinessIdentifier>
                <BKey>CsmNo</BKey>
                <BValue>857895</BValue>
              </BusinessIdentifier>
            </BusinessIdentifiers>
            <BusinessAttributes>
              <BusinessAttribute>
                <BKey>Version</BKey>
                <BValue>1</BValue> 
              </BusinessAttribute>
              <BusinessAttribute>
                <BKey>date</BKey>
                <BValue>2018-06-28</BValue>
              </BusinessAttribute>
            </BusinessAttributes>
          </BusinessObject>
          <BusinessObject>
            <BusinessIdentifiers>
              <BusinessIdentifier>
                <BKey>BuCode</BKey>
                <BValue>CDC</BValue>
              </BusinessIdentifier>
              <BusinessIdentifier>
                <BKey>BuType</BKey>
                <BValue>123</BValue>
              </BusinessIdentifier>
              <BusinessIdentifier>
                <BKey>CsmNo</BKey>
                <BValue>34567</BValue>
              </BusinessIdentifier>
            </BusinessIdentifiers>
            <BusinessAttributes>
              <BusinessAttribute>
                <BKey>Version</BKey>
                <BValue>1</BValue> 
              </BusinessAttribute>
              <BusinessAttribute>
                <BKey>date</BKey>
                <BValue>2018-06-28</BValue>
              </BusinessAttribute>
            </BusinessAttributes>
          </BusinessObject>      
        </BusinessObjects>
        </Input>
```

I would like to get the following output `CDC|123|857895:CDC|123|34567` assigned to `<BIKey>`

I have tried this Xquery as suggested by Martin which actually fixed my ealrier problem but my inputpayload is more as compare to my earlier question:

```
<Input>  
    For $BusinessObject in Input/BusinessObjects/BusinessObject[1]
    retrun


      <BIKey>{ string-join(Input/BusinessObjects/BusinessObject[1]/BusinessIdentifiers/BusinessIdentifier/BValue, '|') }</BIKey>


    </Input>
```

But I got this output

```
CDC|123|857895
```

Please assist on this as i am not sure where to loop the payload to get the required output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `string-join` twice, one call nested into the other:

```
<BIKey>
{
    string-join(
        Input/BusinessObjects/BusinessObject ! string-join(BusinessIdentifiers/BusinessIdentifier/BValue, '|'),
        ':'
    )
}
</BIKey>
```

That way the outer `string-join` joins the sequences of bar separated strings the inner `Input/BusinessObjects/BusinessObject ! string-join(BusinessIdentifiers/BusinessIdentifier/BValue, '|')` returns with a colon.

Example at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbi.

If you don't have XQuery 3 or later you can replace the use of `!` with

```
<Input>
    <BIKey>
    {
        string-join(
            for $bo in Input/BusinessObjects/BusinessObject return string-join($bo/BusinessIdentifiers/BusinessIdentifier/BValue, '|'),
            ':'
        )
    }
    </BIKey>
</Input>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbi/2

Comment: the symbol '!' is not valid in my case as my xquery is not authneticating it. Is there any alternate solution for this.

Comment: The operator `!` is defined in XQuery 3.0 and later, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-map-operator. You should be able to use `for $bo in Input/BusinessObjects/BusinessObject return string-join($bo/BusinessIdentifiers/BusinessIdentifier/BValue, '|')` instead of `Input/BusinessObjects/BusinessObject ! string-join(BusinessIdentifiers/BusinessIdentifier/BValue, '|')`.

Comment: as i dont see the ':', i can see a space ' '.

Comment: The comment clearly said which part you should replace with the `for .. return` expression, see https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbi/2 for the complete sample, only the inner expression that previously used the `!` operator needs to be replaced with the `for .. return`.